# Sound plays on Windows XP but not on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, audio

I wrote a program in Turbo Basic in 1993 that uses the PLAY command. It works fine opening a DOS window in Windows XP and playing the different pitched PC beeps. However in Windows 7, although the DOS window opens and displays the message, at best it is silent and at worst makes a few buzzing noises and sometimes hangs with a continuous note.

Comment: there is no dos in win7 :-) it's a "command prompt". Did you attempt to set it up for compatability? Right click the executable, go to the Compatability tab, and test a bunch of settings, and none of them will fix it, but it is worth a try. Is this a 64bit win7?

Answer (score 3):

The beep API has been replaced in [64 bit editions of windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx).

There is not much you can do to fix it, I have found through some experementing on my own that if you have no sound device installed it will fall back to the old PC speaker but you must have no sound devices installed in windows for this to work.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading somewhere that you can copy some files from an XP machine to 7 to get the functionality back... but I might be thinking of something else.  Now that I am thinking about it, I think it was related to the DOS console beep, not sound in general...

Comment: This is a brilliant answer!

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is you download a DOS program, the most popular I know of is [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) and then run it as you used to!